# Database file created, but no tables are visible in Sqlite3

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm new in Sqlite. I've made the installation like in the tutorial, and tried this simple code (below). Everything is working fine but I still cannot find my database. Where is it stored exactly? Can anyone help me please?

```
var db = openDatabase('newDB', '3.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (email STRING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, username STRING, password STRING, role STRING)');

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;', [], function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log(len);
        console.log(results);
    },
    function(tx, error)
    {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to get the path to the DB file? Which tutorial did you use?

Comment: exactly i need to know the path of my DB..
this is the tutorial that i've found: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Comment: That's not sqlite, its Web SQL.  And it's stored were the browser decides to store it.   You can view the Web SQL database in chrome for example from the developer tools.